# Openssl 1.1.1d invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dsa_st’

Tags: c++, openssl

I am migrating from openssl 1.0.2s to 1.1.1d and getting below error.

I searched on openssl docs and it seems calling the fields has changed. I am not sure how I need to implement that in my code.

```
const BIGNUM * const *KeyPairImpl::getField(const string &field) const
{
  if (field == "P")
    return &dsa_->p;
  else if (field == "Q")
    return &dsa_->q;
  else if (field == "G")
    return &dsa_->g;
  else if (field == "X")
    return &dsa_->priv_key;
  else if (field == "Y")
    return &dsa_->pub_key;
  else
    // unknown field name
    return NULL;
}
```

Error

```
KeyPair.cpp: In member function ‘const BIGNUM* const* KeyPairImpl::getField(const std::string&) const’:
KeyPair.cpp:84: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dsa_st’
/usr/local/ssl_1.1.1d/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:107: error: forward declaration of ‘struct dsa_st’
KeyPair.cpp:86: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dsa_st’
/usr/local/ssl_1.1.1d/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:107: error: forward declaration of ‘struct dsa_st’
KeyPair.cpp:88: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dsa_st’
/usr/local/ssl_1.1.1d/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:107: error: forward declaration of ‘struct dsa_st’
KeyPair.cpp:90: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dsa_st’
/usr/local/ssl_1.1.1d/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:107: error: forward declaration of ‘struct dsa_st’
KeyPair.cpp:92: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct dsa_st’
/usr/local/ssl_1.1.1d/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:107: error: forward declaration of ‘struct dsa_st’
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Openssl 1.1.1 does not allow you direct access to the internal structures any longer.  You need to use the provided API functions to access internal data (if provided).

For dsa_->p use [DSA_get0_p](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DSA_get0_p.html)

For dsa_->q use [DSA_get0_q](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DSA_get0_q.html)

For dsa_->g use [DSA_get0_g](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DSA_get0_g.html)

For dsa_->priv_key use [DSA_get0_priv_key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DSA_get0_priv_key.html)

For dsa_->pub_key use [DSA_get0_pub_key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DSA_get0_pub_key.html)

e.g.

```
return DSA_get0_p(dsa_);
```